# SQLite: updating column from another table

Tags: sqlite

I have a old table and a new table. what i need is to copy the uuId of the old table to the new Table.

im following some answers from other references but i can`t get the ideal answer.

the closest answer i found is this:

```
update table1
set table1.uuid = 
(select table2.uuid from table2 where table1.itemDescription = table2.itemDescription)
```

when i execute this query, it only saves the 1st found uuid of the old table to all the entry in the new Table.

Sample Table2 (old table):

```
uuid|itemDescription
   1|item1
   2|item2
   3|item3
```

Sample Table1 (new Table):

```
uuid|itemDescription
Null|item1
Null|item2
Null|item3
```

Desired Output:

```
uuid|itemDescription
   1|item1
   2|item2
   3|item3
```

what happens:

```
uuid|itemDescription
   1|item1
   1|item2
   1|item3
```

Comment: your `UPDATE` copy `table2.uuid` into `table1.uuid`, however, your sample data do not have any values in `table2.uuid`. Moreover, the `itemDescription` do not correspond in both tables.

Comment: Good day, sorry i edit it to be correct. the table 2 supposed to be the 1st sample. the one with id. and the new table is supposed to be the one with no id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, you must not use the table name in the SET clause:

```
update table1
set uuid = 
(select table2.uuid from table2 where table1.itemDescription = table2.itemDescription);
```

Comment: many thanks i also just found it yesterday, what is wrong with my query but you already post it so i accept it. many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this :

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.uuid = table2.uuid
FROM table2 WHERE table1.itemDescription = table2.itemDescription
```

No need for subquery, otherwise you need to link item description in outer query also

Comment: Gives me an Error near From. 

im using SQLite. and i already get this answer a little while ago T.T